# osx fstab mounting windows share with wrong osx user

Tags: windows, network-share, mac-osx-server, fstab

My fstab on the osx server is as follows:

```
192.168.9.99:/TST /Users/HMTS01/BACKUP cifs automated,username=TEST,password=TEST,uid=hmts01,gid=staff,file_mode=0700,dir_mode=0700 0 0
```

The windows share (TST on 192.168.9.99) is mounted correctly as the BACKUP folder in HMTS01's home folder, however the owner and permissions are wrong.

```
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root    wheel    1  4 May 12:08 BACKUP
drwx------+  3 hmts01  staff  102  4 May 09:20 Desktop
drwx------+  5 hmts01  staff  170  4 May 09:27 Documents
drwx------+  4 hmts01  staff  136  4 May 09:20 Downloads
drwx------+ 29 hmts01  staff  986  4 May 10:03 Library
drwx------+  3 hmts01  staff  102  4 May 09:20 Movies
drwx------+  3 hmts01  staff  102  4 May 09:20 Music
drwx------+  4 hmts01  staff  136  4 May 09:20 Pictures
drwxrwxr-x+  6 hmts01  staff  204  4 May 11:24 Public
drwxr-xr-x+  6 hmts01  staff  204  4 May 09:20 Sites
```

The uid for the folder is root and not hmts01 as specified. Also, the directory doesn't give write access to anyone. I want only hmts01 (osx user) to have full access to the directory.

the parameters are

- windows share

  - 192.168.9.99/TST
  - username:test
  - password:TEST
- osx mount point ~/BACKUP
- mount as hmts01 on osx with permissions 700
- automated at boot

Any help will be much appreciated.

It would be awesome if someone could help explain the formatting of the fstab line.

Answer (score 0):

When you created /Users/HMTS01/BACKUP, how did you set its ownership and permissions?  You may need to set the mount point's metainfo manually before mounting the filesystem.

Comment: the folders permissions before mounting are: user and group HTMS01 0777